# Command binding in XAML using x:static

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a CommandBinding in XAML to a static function in a static class. The compiler (VS) will not accept but says `The member "CloseCanExecute" is not recognized or is not accessible.` However using private non-static members are accepted and I can also access a static string (see button).

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="tt_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tt_WPF"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <!-- THIS WILL NOT COMPILE -->
    <CommandBinding Command="Close" 
    Executed="{x:Static local:XXX.CloseExecuted}" />
    <!-- THIS IS WORKING
    <CommandBinding Command="Close" 
    Executed="CloseExecuted" />
    -->
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Button  Content="{x:Static local:XXX.SomeStaticString}" />
</Window>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
public static class XXX
{
    public static string SomeStaticString = "Hello World";
    public static void CloseExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey, I'm closing.");
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void CloseExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey, I'm closing.");
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: `CloseCanExecute` doesn't exist.

Comment: Good catch, sorry. But that's not the reason. I corrected my posting. I removed the "Can..." function in order to shorten the posted code.

Comment: @JohannesSchacht - I'm afraid but you can't do that with x:Static but you can bind to static handlers from code behind.

Comment: Thank you, Rohit. Would you know how I would find out what's possible in XAML and what's not?

Comment: WPF doesn't have well written down XAML restrictions document (AFAIK). So, google and SO is your only friend it seems. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the comments, you ***can't bind to static handlers via x:Static in XAML*** but you can definitely do that from code behind.

On window load event or from window constructor you can add the command binding with static handlers.

```
this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close, 
                                            XXX.CloseExecuted));
```